# populating multidimensional array from mysql hieararchy table to php

Tags: php, mysql

I am going straight to the question.

I have a table, with 3 columns: "id", "name" and "parent".
Each id represents categories, and the parent is the id which references the subcategory.

I need to build a menu, so, an unordered list and nested unordered lists.
I came to the conclusion I have to transform that in an array, is there another way using just mysql; and if not could you indicate me the technique to build the multidimensional array in php?

Comment: try this

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053857/php-multi-dimensional-array-from-mysql-result>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178778/database-tree-to-multidimensional-array/2178823#2178823

Comment: This second one seem to work. Now, I have to understand why it works... :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with another code that doesn't use recursivity:

```
<?php
//Let's say the DB returns:
$categories = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Category 1', 'parent' => null ),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'Category 2', 'parent' => null ),
    array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Category 3', 'parent' => 1 ),
    array( 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'Category 4', 'parent' => 3)
    );


$sortedCategories = assignChildren( $categories );

function assignChildren( &$categories )
{
    $sortedCategories = array();
    foreach( $categories as &$category )
    {
        if ( !isset( $category['children'] ) )
        {
            // set the children
            $category['children'] = array();
            foreach( $categories as &$subcategory )
            {
                if( $category['id'] == $subcategory['parent'] )
                {
                    $category['children'][] = &$subcategory;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( is_null( $category['parent'] ) )
        {
            $sortedCategories[] = &$category;
        }

    }

    return $sortedCategories;
}

var_dump( $sortedCategories );
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Category 1"
    ["parent"]=>
    NULL
    ["children"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      &array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
        ["name"]=>
        string(10) "Category 3"
        ["parent"]=>
        int(1)
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          &array(4) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(4)
            ["name"]=>
            string(10) "Category 4"
            ["parent"]=>
            int(3)
            ["children"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Category 2"
    ["parent"]=>
    NULL
    ["children"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the method is to prepare your multi-dimensional array as below ... it maynot be the perfect but it has worked well for me ...

```
$result_category = mysql_query('select all records query here ...');
    $categoryData = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);

while ($categoryItem = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_category))
{
    $categoryData['items'][$categoryItem['category_id']] = $categoryItem;
    $categoryData['parents'][$categoryItem['parent_id']][] = $categoryItem['category_id'];
}
```

Comment: Yes but what if children have children themselves? how is (s)he going to render his list ?

Comment: @Bgi 'parents' array will contain all references to all parent-child relationships

Comment: Ok, but how do you render the list ? Using array_search ?

Comment: You can render list, build drop-downs, un-ordered lists or however you want to present the data... it'll be a 2 steps process 1. you prepare above array 2. you loop through each item, best to do in a separate function/method, and build your list.

Answer (score 0):

You must make a Database call to get once the list of all the categories.

Then you must use a recursive function to assign to every category its subcategories, and to each subcategory its subcategories and again and again (thanks to recursivity this is "easy")....

Comment: The first is easy, I already knew it. :-) the second part make me think.